# How to define an observable on a subsystem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, observables, trace

Suppose we have a bipartite system $AB$. I would intuitively say that an observable $O$ "acts as the identity on $A$" if

$$ O=\mathbb 1_A \otimes O_B$$

But then I would also say this if

$$ \mathrm{Tr}_B(O)=\mathbb 1_A$$

yet these two definitions clash with each other, as using the first one

$$\mathrm{Tr}_B(O)=\mathrm{Tr}(O_B)\mathbb 1_A $$

and $O_B$ might very well be traceless, or even worse, if $O=\mathbb 1_A\otimes\mathbb 1_B$, the partial trace on both subsystem is not the identity but a scalar times the identity. What is the correct definition? Is there some more sensible way of restricting observables on a subsystem that is not the partial trace?

I think the confusion stems from the fact that the important thing is expectation values in some state $\rho_{AB}$, and clearly

$$\mathrm{Tr}(O_{AB}\rho_{AB})\neq \mathrm{Tr}_{A}(\mathrm{Tr}_{B}(O_{AB})\mathrm{Tr}_{B}(\rho_{AB}))$$

so I think I'm looking for an observable $R$ such that

$$\mathrm{Tr}(O_{AB}\rho_{AB})= \mathrm{Tr}_{A}(R_A\mathrm{Tr}_{B}(\rho_{AB})) $$
for all $\rho$. I wouldn't be surprised if such a thing doesn't exist though.

P.S. I understand this is mostly a math question, but I think it's more about physical modeling. Let me know if it should be in math.se, though I doubt it will get an answer there!